# Need help for substituting name in string problem (clojure)

Tags: java, clojure

I'm doing an Exercism problem for Clojure. It should be simple, but it's actually giving me a headache.
The problem description is as follows:

> Two-fer or 2-fer is short for two for one. One for you and one for me.
> Given a name, return a string with the message: "One for X, one for me."
> Where X is the given name.
> However, if the name is missing, return the string: "One for you, one for me."

This is what I've tried:

```
(defn two-fer [& name]
  (if (nil? name)
    "One for you, one for me."
    (str "One for " name ", one for me."
  )
)
```

However, I ended up getting this the following unit test output:

> expected: (= "One for Bob, one for me." (two-fer/two-fer "Bob"))
> actual: (not (= "One for Bob, one for me." "One for ("Bob"), one for me."))
>
> lein test :only two-fer-test/name-alice-test
>
> FAIL in (name-alice-test) (two_fer_test.clj:9)
> expected: (= "One for Alice, one for me." (two-fer/two-fer "Alice"))
> actual: (not (= "One for Alice, one for me." "One for ("Alice"), one for me."))
>
> ERROR in (two-fer-test) (two_fer.clj:5)
> expected: (= "One for you, one for me." (two-fer/two-fer))
> actual: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class clojure.lang.IFn (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; clojure.lang.IFn is in unnamed module of loader 'app')

I've also tried:

```
(defn two-fer [& name]
  (str "One for " (if (nil? name) "you" name) ", one for me.")
)
```

```
(defn two-fer [& name]
  (if (nil? name)
    "One for you, one for me."
    (eval `(str "One for " ~name ", one for me.")
  )
)
```

```
(defn two-fer [& name]
  (if nil? name)
    "One for you, one for me."
    (clojure.string/replace (str "One for " name ", one for me.") #"\\(?\\"\\)" ""))
  )
)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can write multi-arity function:

```
(defn two-fer
  ([] (two-fer "you"))
  ([name] (str "One for " name ", one for me.")))
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the `&` symbol, which wraps an arbitrary number of arguments into a list/seq.

You probably need something like this:

```
(defn two-fer
  [& args]
  (let [name (if (empty? args)
               "you"
               (first args))]
    (str "One for " name ", one for me.")))
```

with result

```
(two-fer "Bob")  => "One for Bob, one for me."
(two-fer)        => "One for you, one for me."
```

You may also be interested in this [list of documentation sources](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation).

Answer (score 2):

```
(defn two-fer [& names]
  (str "One for " (if (empty? names) "you" (first names)) ", and one for me."))

;; or using `or` (old lisp style, not Clojure's best practice):
(defn two-fer [& names]
  (str "One for " (or (first names) "you") ", and one for me."))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd always go with the [two-arity version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66482325/3181392) in such a case.  Yet your
example *nearly* works if you would destructure the first of the "rest" of the arguments.

```
(defn two-fer
  [& [name]]
  (if (nil? name)
    "One for you, one for me."
    (str "One for " name ", one for me.")))

(println (two-fer) (two-fer "Bob"))
; → One for you, one for me. One for Bob, one for me.
```

Comment: Or `(format "One for %s, one for me." (or name "you"))`

Comment: Or `(str "One for " (or name "you") ", one for me.")`

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite it to handle all the names you pass it:

```
(defn two-fer [& names]
  (if (nil? names)
    "One for you, one for me."
    (str "One for " (apply str (interpose ", " names)) ", one for me.")
  )
)
```

Test as follows:

```
user=> (two-fer)
"One for you, one for me."
user=> (two-fer "John")
"One for John, one for me."
user=> (two-fer "John" "Paul" "George" "Ringo")
"One for John, Paul, George, Ringo, one for me."
```

### EDIT

And because there's no kill like overkill:

```
(defn two-fer [& names]
  (let [all-names (conj (if (nil? names) ["you"] (vec names)) "me")
        comma     (if (< (count all-names) 2) ", " ", one for ")]
    (str "One for "  (apply str (interpose comma all-names)))
  )
)
```

Test results:

```
user=> (two-fer)
"One for you, one for me"
user=> (two-fer "John")
"One for John, one for me"
user=> (two-fer "John" "Paul" "George" "Ringo")
"One for John, one for Paul, one for George, one for Ringo, one for me"
```